# Table not listed in generated abi file

Tags: cleos, nodeos

This is my sample code. Tables are not generated when I compile the contract. Whats wrong?

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/transaction.hpp>
#include <string>


using namespace eosio;
using std::string;

class test1: public contract {


    public:

    using contract::contract;
    test1(name receiver, name code,  datastream<const char*> ds):contract(receiver, code, ds) {}


        [[eosio::action]]
      void hi( name user ) {
         print( "Hello, UEL , nice to meet you", user);
      }

  private:
  struct [[eosio::table]] person {
    name key;
    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
    std::string street;
    std::string city;
    std::string state;
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return key.value; }
  };
  typedef eosio::multi_index<"people"_n, person> address_index;

};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(test1,(hi));
```

The output is

```
{
    "____comment": "This file was generated with eosio-abigen. DO NOT EDIT Tue Dec  4 00:55:47 2018",
    "version": "eosio::abi/1.1",
    "structs": [
        {
            "name": "hi",
            "base": "",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "user",
                    "type": "name"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "types": [],
    "actions": [
        {
            "name": "hi",
            "type": "hi",
            "ricardian_contract": ""
        }
    ],
    "tables": [],
    "ricardian_clauses": [],
    "variants": [],
    "abi_extensions": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the syntax for instantiating the class to the new format:

```
class [[eosio::contract]] test1: public contract {


    public:

    // using contract::contract; // older syntax
```

In order to use the table, you'll need to declare a variable of the table's type below the typdef.  For that to work, you'll need to add the name of that table to the class constructor.

```
  // added table to constructor
  test1(name receiver, name code,  datastream<const char*> ds):contract(receiver, code, ds), _persons(receiver, code.value) {}

  typedef eosio::multi_index<"people"_n, person> address_index;
  // added table declaration so you can use table
  address_index _persons;
};

EOSIO_DISPATCH(test1,(hi));
```